# Webpack 2 ES6 import UMD without default export

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, es6-modules, ts-loader

I'm trying to import UMD libraries using Webpack 2 and `ts-loader`. It used to work using Webpack 1 and Rollup (without TypeScript), but Webpack 2 appends `.default` when invoking imported function.

For example:

```
import canvg from 'canvg';
canvg();
```

transforms into

```
var canvg_1 = require("canvg");
canvg_1.default();
```

and I get `Uncaught TypeError: canvg_1.default is not a function`.

How to fix it?

Comment: @AndrewLi I'm importing some external libraries with UMD, for example https://github.com/canvg/canvg/blob/master/canvg.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was in TypeScript config, I've added a `module: 'es2015'` into my `tsconfig.json` and it worked. Also `allowSyntheticDefaultImports: true` may help in some cases (not necessary in my case, some analog for `babel-plugin-add-module-exports` described by @alejandro-garcia-anglada).

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "es2015",
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `babel-plugin-add-module-exports` you can make sure everything works as expected.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-add-module-exports

Comment: I don't use Babel and cannot change UMD of external library. Though if it will cut `default`, I can use if for a single file.

Comment: Okay, I think you wont be able to use it that way. Just do `import 'canvg';` and then use it as the documentation says: `window.canvg() `

Comment: You solved a case with canvg, thanks. Also I had a problem with es6-promise lib and had to disable it, will read more about inserting polyfills using webpack. Do library owners now have to declare default in their UMD?

Comment: They are not really force to do that, if they want to keep the `umd` way of exporting things. But they should be because we are all (normally) working with modules. About the polyfills, take a look at `ProvidePlugin` from webpack ;)